# Do a TIMESTAMPDIFF for each MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have a little problem with a MySQL query, this is my MySQL database structure:

table user

```
hid(PK)
```

table request

```
id (PK), hid, word, time
```

table click

```
id, rid (FK),time
```

i should get the average time between the request and its related click... i've tried this but i'm not sure if it's working properly:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,r.time,c.time) 
FROM requests r RIGHT JOIN clicks c ON r.id=c.rid 
WHERE r.hid='$hid'
```

Could someone please tell me if I'm doing it right and explain me why I'm not? I'm getting some numbers as query results, but they don't seem to be right

Comment: what is the data format of r.time and c.time? what kind of output are you looking for? time in seconds?

Comment: datatype of both columns? create a sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: tip: use `MICROSECOND` as unit  as per the need you specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the **average** time, you forgot to use it in your query (which looks fine besides forgetting "averaging" results).

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,r.time,c.time)) as avg_secs_diff
FROM requests r RIGHT JOIN clicks c ON r.id=c.rid 
WHERE r.hid='$hid'
GROUP BY r.hid
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, i forgot writing thr AVG function, but is the other part of the query right?

Comment: Try out mine and see for yourself. I suggest creating temporary table/data, where only you control the values, and see if you always get the correct (expected) result. I'm pretty confident my answer is correct :)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. Your query returns only 1 row, what I wanted to do is this: for each request, there is (not always) an associated click (with the relation r.id=c.rid).
For each request with an associated click, I have to get the average time difference between the request time and the click time of that request. However, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: This is not OP asking for